# Couldnt use a custom font - "file not found"

Tags: vb.net, fonts, privatefontcollection

I was following this: http://zerosandtheone.com/blogs/vb/archive/2009/11/20/vb-net-include-a-font-as-an-embedded-resource-in-your-application.aspx to allow my application to use a custom fonts in a labels. The problem with that is I can run the application on my computer (probably because I have this font installed), the problem appears when any other person run the compiled application on his computer; the following error from the exception catch appears: `53 File doesn't exists`.

Where does this exception is located at?

I'm talking about the module I linked above:

```
'MATTHEW KLEINWAKS
'ZerosAndTheOne.com
'2009
'CUSTOM FONT LOADED DYNAMICALLY FROM A RESOURCE

Imports System.Drawing.Text
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module CustomFont

    'PRIVATE FONT COLLECTION TO HOLD THE DYNAMIC FONT
    Private _pfc As PrivateFontCollection = Nothing


    Public ReadOnly Property GetInstance(ByVal Size As Single, _
                                         ByVal style As FontStyle) As Font
        Get
            'IF THIS IS THE FIRST TIME GETTING AN INSTANCE
            'LOAD THE FONT FROM RESOURCES
            If _pfc Is Nothing Then LoadFont()

            'RETURN A NEW FONT OBJECT BASED ON THE SIZE AND STYLE PASSED IN
            Return New Font(_pfc.Families(0), Size, style)

        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub LoadFont()
        Try
            'INIT THE FONT COLLECTION
            _pfc = New PrivateFontCollection

            'LOAD MEMORY POINTER FOR FONT RESOURCE
            Dim fontMemPointer As IntPtr = _
                Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem( _
                My.Resources.DIGITALDREAMNARROW.Length)

            'COPY THE DATA TO THE MEMORY LOCATION
            Marshal.Copy(My.Resources.DIGITALDREAMNARROW, _
                         0, fontMemPointer, _
                         My.Resources.DIGITALDREAMNARROW.Length)

            'LOAD THE MEMORY FONT INTO THE PRIVATE FONT COLLECTION
            _pfc.AddMemoryFont(fontMemPointer, _
                               My.Resources.DIGITALDREAMNARROW.Length)

            'FREE UNSAFE MEMORY
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontMemPointer)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(& Err.Number & " " & Err.Description)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Module
```

precisely this:

```
   Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(& Err.Number & " " & Err.Description)
    End Try
```

Is showing the message box, containing the `53 File doesn't exists` message.

I don't really know why does it happends, because it works on my computer without any problems... I would appreciate any help attempt!

Comment: Remove the FreeCoTaskMem call.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code

```
''' <summary>Adds the specified font to the private font collection.</summary>
''' <param name="font">The font to be added.</param>
Public Sub AddFont(ByVal font As Byte())
    If font Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("The font cannot be null.", "font")
    If font.Length = 0 Then Throw New ArgumentException("The length of the font array cannot be 0.", "font")
    Try
        privateFonts.AddMemoryFont(Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(font, 0), font.Length)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'handle you exceptions here
    End Try
End Sub
```

And add fonts to the collection this way

```
Private Sub LoadFont()
    Try
        'INIT THE FONT COLLECTION
        privateFonts = New PrivateFontCollection
        AddFont(My.Resources.DIGITALDREAMNARROW)
    Catch
    
    '   
    ' the rest of your code
    '
End Sub
```

Assuming you added the font resource as a file, it is going to be passed to the `AddFont` method as a byte array.

Needless to say, the `AddFont` method assumes you have an initialized PrivateFontCollection object called `privateFonts` which is accessible within the scope of the method.

#### Update

Since you're saying that my solution is not working, I've uploaded a sample project [here](http://ge.tt/2COX9iS/v/0). Download and see how to load and use private fonts from resources.

Comment: Should I replace the `_pfc.AddMemoryFont(fontMemPointer, _
                               My.Resources.DIGITALDREAMNARROW.Length)` line with the `AddFont(My.Resources.DIGITALDREAMNARROW)`?

Comment: Yes, replace everything that comes after `_pfc = New PrivateFontCollection` with `AddFont(My.Resources.DIGITALDREAMNARROW)`. (*see my edit*)

Comment: Its still the same. Except that now, the exception comes from the `AddFont` function. Here is my whole code: http://pastebin.com/fhFx3pqz .

Comment: When I'm trying to open the `PrivateFonts.vbproj`, nothing happends.

Comment: which version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'nothing happens'. I downloaded the code and run it on my VS 2010 & VS 2012 successfully. I cleaned and purged the project of redundant files so no designer/editor window opens when you load the project. Check the Solution Explorer to see the files in the project. If it still doesn't work, import the files into your project one by one. If that too doesn't work then I'm afraid you'll have to look for a solution elsewhere.